# phpmyadmin allow empty values in the DB without using the Null value

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database and wanted to have empty values that will be updated later on. I dont want the values to be defined as null and when I use None as the default I get a database error when trying to enter values into the database. Help I dont want to use Null. Im running mysql on phpmyadmin.

Is there a configuration on phpmyadmin that would allow empty values to be passed or allow empty strings (without using the NULL)?

Comment: How do I do it on phpmyadmin???

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT NULL` when defining the column. Or, in phpmyadmin, simply don't check the `NULL` checkbox.

Comment: Not null means there has to be a value. I just wanted an empty field that will be updated later on

Comment: You can leave the field empty (= no value)

Comment: When I leave as none it gives me an error that nothing has been passed on that field

Comment: hmm - not here...

Comment: Is there a configuration on the phpmyadmin that would allow empty values to be passed or allow empty strings?

Comment: I never have a problem (i.e. get any error messages) when I simply ignore such a field in an insert query

Comment: Maybe you should describe the situation where your problem actually pops up? Like, post the code of your query / form / whatever when "trying to enter values into the database".

Comment: When NULL is unchecked this is the error:    {PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'phone' cannot be null in /home1/collages/public_html/form-mailers.php:16}

Answer (score 0):

For varchar, text or blob fields You can use '' as an value.

Comment: I just want the fields to be completely blank